# How do I eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jekyll

I have built out a Jekyll blog with AngularJS and have used it exclusively except for the slick slider that is in above-the-fold content. The slider requires JQuery so I have added that into my application as well but have referenced it bellow my angular scripts. Since it is the first thing people see I want it to load first but I'm not too sure how to do that because it wont work if I place it before the Angular scripts. My scripts go as follows:

```
<script src="{{ site.baseurl}}/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/bower_components/angular-slick/dist/slick.min.js"></script>

<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/js/app.module.js"></script>
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/js/app.controller.js"></script>
```

I have added a script for deferred loading and placed it just above the closing body tag that looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "/js/defer.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

In my defer.js file I have been able to add a few small scripts to help with deferred loading of social buttons but I am still stuck on how to use it so that my slider is the first thing that loads. I would greatly appreciate any help or tips that anyone has for this kind of problem. If you need a look into the source code my Github is Glasser88 and the website is hosted on Github Pages as www.lifeofglass.com. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First, Google would argue against carousels in general, as they're above the fold, slow to load and so on. But Google pages are utilitarian at best, so you can ignore their admonishments to some extent.

That said, consider combining all those many .js files into one, minified .js which should have a significant impact on your load times. When it comes to building a quick application, the *number* of .js files often has a bigger impact than the *size* of those files.

Comment: I ended up removing it and putting it more of a poor mans version that is just angular material md-tabs that doesn't slide automatically. I combined the scripts and that has definitely helped with the load times. But I am still getting the "Your page has 3 blocking script resources and 3 blocking CSS resources." I just have one css file but I am importing two google fonts. My mobile is at 61/100 and desktop is 84/100. I am also getting this warning. "None of the final above-the-fold content could be rendered even with the full HTML response."